# Rename a strongly named assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, strongname, ilmerge

I have two 3rd party assemblies that happen to have the same name and both need to be referenced by my assembly. Both assemblies are strongly named, and my assembly is strongly named too.

**How can I rename one of the assemblies, and keep it strongly typed with the same name?** The referenced assemblies do not have any other reference apart from System assemblies.

Does ILMERGE help in that? I know I can rename and sign an assembly with ILMERGE but I want to keep the same signing of the original assembly (not to provide a different key).

**UPDATE**

For now, I used ILMERGE to re-sign one of the two assemblies with my key, and under a different name. I know ILMERGE updates any code references to types within the assembly so their Fully Qualified Name includes the new assembly's name and public key. I hope there is no any dynamic (reflection based) access to types and methods. I suppose that would result in an error.

If, however, there is an answer to my initial question (either positive or negative) I would like to know.

Comment: You cannot do this without the signing key. You *can* remove the signature all together though.

Comment: I dont think you can rename a strongly typed assembly as what would be the essence of saying it stongly typed then

Comment: "I have two 3rd party assemblies that happen to have the same name ..." That sounds really strange to me. .Net assembly names typically include the name of the company that made it, like "JetBrains.Annotations" or "DevExpress.BonusSkins", and I think Microsoft recommends this in order to avoid the chances of conflicts. You're not thinking of the filename, rather than the assembly name are you?

Comment: @RenniePet yes it is strange, yet real. ExcelDataReader and JetCell Excel, both deliver an assembly named "Excel.dll". That's really NOT smart. Excel.dll is so obvious name, anyone could use it.

Comment: Are one of these two products small enough that it is feasible to "hack" it by dissassembling all of its assemblies and renaming the Excel assembly and reassembling them and signing them with your own strong name?

Comment: And as a more long-range solution, tell the companies behind both products to clean their act up in the future. As soon as one does you can drop your hacked solution.

Comment: Wait a minute, Excel.dll must be the interop assembly for office automation for Excel. So the two Excel.dlls are probably the same. But you say they've been signed differently? See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax7sdch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx The two companies should be using PIAs supplied by Microsoft, not ones they've signed themselves.

Comment: @RenniePet No they are not the same assebly. Both assemblies don't depend on PIAs or any installation of MS Excel. They are stand alone solutions. The product names are "ExcelDataReader" (you can find it in nuget) and "JetCell Excel" (commercial product). They both deliver their assembly as "Excel.dll". I needed to use both because each one doesn't support all the features I need.

In the end, I used ILMERGE to re-sing one of the two assemblies with my own key, and name, hoping there isn't any dynamic (reflection based) invokation or instatiation used within the assembly.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I was curious. And I really think you should tell the two companies to change the naming of that assembly. Tell them it's unprofessional - you can quote me on that, and provide a link to this thread. :-)

Comment: @RenniePet I will certainly do. The funny part about the commercial product is that the trial version assembly is also differently named as "Docs.Excel.dll". Which worked well when I tested it together with the other product. So when we ordered the full version it was a surprise to see the assembly with a different, much more simpler and common name!